# KeyError when data encoded as string

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, types

After struggle with a plotting code, i finally end up with the following minimal working example:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'foo': ['2', '335', '3'],
    'bar': [1, 2, 1],
}

pandas.DataFrame(data).plot.scatter('foo', 'bar')  # KeyError
plt.show()
```

Which raise a `KeyError: 'foo'`.

However, if i use integers in the `foo` data instead of strings:

```
'foo': [2, 335, 3],
```

I get the expected scatterplot, without error.

What is the rationale about this DataFrame behavior ?
I can understand that all data must be in the same format. But why raise a (very laconic) KeyError in this case ?

Comment: Probably scatter is selecting a sub-dataframe with numerical columns (since you cannot do a scatter plot of categorical variables) and that dataframe doesn't have that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is no longer the case in newer versions.**

The error that gets raised now is: `ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric`, which is a much more informative error.

In any case, I assume the reason for the original `KeyError` was the use of the internal function `_get_numeric_data` (under the super class `NDFrame`) inside the plot function. This removed the non-numeric columns before attempting to plot, thus raising a `KeyError` since the non-numeric column 'foo' was dropped.